# Promise resolves when a method is called

Tags: angular, service, promise, components, typescript-typings

I have a component A that can display an image:

```
<img *ngIf="manageImgService.isImg" (click)="manageImgService.hideImg()" src="...">
```

I also have a service (manageImgService) to manage when the image is displayed:

```
export class manageImgService{
  isImg = false;
  session?: Promise<'wasClosed'>;

  showImg() {
    if (this.isImg) return;

    this.isOpen = true;
    this.session = new Promise<1>((resolve) => {
      //help
    });
    return this.session;
  }

  hideImg() {
    if (!this.session) return;

    //help
    this.session = undefined;
    this.isOpen = false;
  }
}
```

I need this so that I can show the image from another component B and that component B is also informed when the image is closed again.

```
export class otherBComponent {
    constructor(private manageImgService: ManageImgService){}

    showImg(){
        const res = this.manageImgService.showImg()
        if (!res) return;

        res.then((value) => console.log('image was hidden'));
    }
}
```

How can I make this logic work?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Angular (and thus have RxJS baked in by default), this kind of behaviour can be achieved using a [`Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject)

```
export class manageImgService {
  isImageShownSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>
}
```

```
export class otherBComponent {
    constructor(private manageImgService: ManageImgService){}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.watchForImageChanges()
    }

    // How to notify a component of changes to the image display state
    watchForImageChanges(){
      this.manageImgService.isImageShownSubject
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe({
          next: (isImageShown: boolean) => {
            // Logic goes here
            console.log(isImageShown)
          }
        })
    }

    // How to change the display state of the image from the component
    showImgFromComponent(): void {
      this.manageImgService.isImageShownSubject.next(true);
    }

    hideImgFromComponent(): void {
      this.manageImgService.isImageShownSubject.next(false);
    }
}
```

In practice a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#behaviorsubject) may be preferable, as this will also allow you to emit a default value on creation of the subject (normal Subjects only emit a value the first time you call `.next()`)

```
export class manageImgService {
  isImageShownSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true) // default value goes here
  // ...
}
```

If you only need the value of `isImageShown` in the template, you can further simplify this through the use of the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe. There would be no need to also have this value exposed in the component `.ts` file, and so `watchForImageChanges` can be omitted.

```
export class otherBComponent {
    constructor(public manageImgService: ManageImgService) {}
}
```

```
<div>{{ manageImgService.isImageShownSubject | async }}</div>
// Will show true or false and update whenever the subject emits a new value
```